# T-SQL GROUP BY a nvarchar error

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a request kindly:

Here is the data:

Table 1: `EMPLOYEE`

```
    FK: DID
    PK: Name 
    UserName
```

Table 2: `DEPARTMENT`

```
    PK: DID
    TerminationDate
```

I’m looking to find the number of terminated employees in the quarter.  Here is the T-SQL so far:

```
SELECT 
    DEPARTMENT.name AS Name,
    COUNT(e.userName)
FROM
    EMPLOYEE AS e
JOIN 
    DEPARTMENT ON e.department = DEPARTMENT.DID

UNION 

SELECT
    u.eu, u.name 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         dd.name, COUNT(ee.userName) AS eu
     FROM 
         DEPARTMENT AS dd
     JOIN 
         EMPLOYEE AS ee ON dd.DID = ee.department
                        AND ee.terminationDate IS NOT NULL
     WHERE
         ee.terminationDate IS NOT NULL
         AND ee.terminationDate BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-06-30'
     GROUP BY 
         dd.name, ee.userName) AS u
GROUP BY 
    u.eu, u.name, Name      
ORDER BY 
    Name
```

The error is:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'DEPARTMENT.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: GROUP BY dd.name, ee.userName make it as GROUP BY dd.name in 2nd query and remove u.eu

Comment: With t-sql all non-aggregated columns in the select statement must be included in the group by clause, so in the first query you need to add a group by clause for _department.name_

Comment: Also, you switch places between the count and name in the second query; the union must have the same data types for all columns so you need to change the order too.

Comment: If you just want the count of employees terminated in the specific period then your query can be simplified a lot. What is the actual output you want?

Comment: What is the actual output you want? Thanks, the output I'm looking for is the number of terminated employees in the quarter.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your query, you list the department name in your select clause but don't include it in a group by clause (because it is missing)

```
select DEPARTMENT.name as Name, COUNT(e.userName)
from EMPLOYEE as e
join DEPARTMENT on e.department = DEPARTMENT.DID
group by DEPARTMENT.Name --add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of problems with this query are bewildering.  To start with... The table definitions you have listed do not match your query.  You have the `TerminationDate` as an attribute of the `DEPARTMENT` table, where as in the query it looks like you are accessing it though the `EMPLOYEE` table, which makes sense to be there.  So I'm going to assume that your table structure really is:

Table 1: EMPLOYEE

```
FK: DID
PK: Name 
UserName
TerminationDate
```

Table 2: DEPARTMENT

```
PK: DID
Name
```

The way you have used a `UNION` in this query leads me to believe that you have a misunderstanding of what a `UNION` statement does.  `UNION` is used to join two sets into one. So in set theory {1,2,3} union {3, 4} is {1,2,3,3,4}.  In SQL Server, you have to make sure that the types and number of columns in the first select statement match all the selects that are unioned with it.  So for example:

```
 Select 1 A, 2 B
 Union
 Select 3 B
```

Will give this error because the first select has two columns and the second has only one:

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 All queries combined using a UNION,
>   INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions
>   in their target lists.

And this query:

```
 Select 1 A
 Union
 Select 'Bob' A
```

Will give this error because the column types do not match:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'Bob' to data type int.

If all you are looking for is the number of employees terminated between two dates, then there really isn't really anything you need to union.  All the employees are already together in one set (the `Employee` table)... and you just need to filter the dates you want and count the record total.  You don't even need the `DEPARTMENT` table to calculate this.

I could write the query for you... but I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I forgot to include that I'm also looking for the department name and department employee count: Table 1: EMPLOYEE PK: ID, Name, username, FK: DepartmentID. Table 2: DEPARTMENT PK DepartmentId, DepartmentName so overall I'm looking for the number of employees in a department and the number of employees that have been fired within the quarter in one result set. So if there were 20 departments with 5 employees per department and a total of 2 employees were terminated during the last quarter the result set would be 20 rows with something like this as a row: | Accounting | 20 | 0 |

Comment: We've found a solution - thank you. A common table expression was needed: